# netmiko : enable a cisco device

Tags: python, networking

I need to execute command on ios device(3750-switch) in enable mode

given: IP, username, password, protocol is telnet, enable password
module: netmiko

challenge: login to device -> enable enable mode -> execute command
I need help with syntax for triggering the enable mode on the device
enable password is put against secret.

The function to trigger enable mode is device.enable() but i might be wrong.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_3x={
   'device_type': 'cisco_ios_telnet',
   'ip': 'address',
   'username': 'xxx',
   'password': 'xxx',
   'secret': 'xxx',
    }
mansingh=ConnectHandler(**cisco_3x)
mansingh.enable()
output=mansingh.send_command("show running")
print output
```

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this code :

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler


cisco_Router = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "host": "router01",
    "username": "your_username",
    "password": "your_password"}

with ConnectHandler(**cisco_Router) as net_connect:

    net_connect.enable()
    result = net_connect.send_command('do show running')
    net_connect.disconnect()

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have level 15 access to the switch you don't need the enable password.

You give level 15 like this:
username user1 privilege 15 secret goodpassword

David Bombal have a couple of examples on configuring switches here:
https://github.com/davidbombal/pythonvideos/blob/master/netmiko2.py

for devices in all_devices:

```
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
for n in range (2,21):
   print "Creating VLAN " + str(n)
   config_commands = ['vlan ' + str(n), 'name Python_VLAN ' + str(n)]
   output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
   print output
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct way!!!
on the other hand David Bombal supossed that you have a level15 user configured on the switch.

you can check the console promtp after enable with this command

```
print(mansingh.find_prompt())
```